Entering a GDAL command in QGIS
I saw the post "Shifting extent and data values of NetCDF with GDAL" describing the same problem as I have with the following solution:
gdalwarp \
-s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=200" \
-t_srs EPSG:4326 \
-te -180 -90 180 90 \
-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 \
NETCDF:oscar_vel10126.nc:u \
u.tif

However, I have not yet managed to insert this command correctly, so I was wondering if anyone could help me (preferably with screenshots of the QGIS window)

Did you try just using your desktop command line?

The GDAL - Raster projections - Warp (reproject) tool uses the gdalwarp command internally, so you can enter the following arguments in the Advanced Parameters - Additional command-line parameters section of the tool dialog:
-s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=200"
-t_srs EPSG:4326
-te -180 -90 180 90 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 

E.g.

Output:


That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!
